# Frequency count of for loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, for-loop

I am having trouble understanding the following:

Consider this loop:

```
for (j=1;j<n;j++)
    //j=1 will run once
    //j<n will run n-1+1 = n times
    //j++ will run n-1 times (one less than the conditional statement above)
```

Now consider the following:

```
for (j=3;j<=n;j++)
    //j=3 will run once
    //j<=n will run n-3+2 = n-1 times
```

Now, I would have said that j++ will run n-2 times, but according to my lecture notes it will run 2(n-2) times.

I don't see how that makes sense, for example if n = 5, the loop will check if j<=n 4 times, but will only increment 3 times. According to the notes it will increment 6 times?

Comment: Something is amiss here.  Are you sure this loop isn't nested inside another loop?  Perhaps the inner loop is running multiple times?

Comment: Your first example is not correct. 'j<n' is executed *n* times, (not *n-1*), and 'j=3' is never executed (you mean: 'j=1')

Comment: perhaps incorrect lecture notes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (j=1;j<n;j++)
```

is equivalent (in C) to

```
j = 1;
while (j < n) {
   ...
   j++;
}
```

Try with a small value for `j`, e.g. 2: `j < 2` is tested 2 times (n) and `j++` once (n-1).

In the 2nd case

```
for (j=3;j<=n;j++)
```

for `n = 4`, `j<=n` is tested 3 times (n-1), `j++` 2 times (n-1) and not 2(n-2). Actually you can say that `j++` will be executed only when the condition is true, i.e. *number of times condition is tested* minus one (provided that the loop does not *break* before, in C and other similar languages).

The difference between the two samples is `j<n` vs `j<=n`: in C, you can translate (for integers comparison)

```
j <= n
```

to

```
j < n+1
```

which may help to understand what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example (assuming n >= 1) the counts for `j<n` should be just n.

For the second example (assuming n >= 2) the count for `j<=n` is n-1 and for `j++` its n-2.

Your understanding is correct, this is wrong in the lecture notes.